# windows partition manager gives an error when trying to shrink the main partition

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning

Whenever I attempt to shrink the main partition to make a bit more room for Ubuntu it gives the error

```
The volume you selected to shrink may be corrupted. Use Chkdsk to fix the corruption problem
```

Chkdsk said that there are no issues. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would try to shrink it with `gparted` on the Ubuntu Live CD (but back up first, of course).

Comment: yes, this worked. could you type it up into an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to modify partition sizes under the host operating system, if I can. However, the system drive is difficult, as its contents are constantly changing, including during disc checks, which is probably the reason for the possible corruption you have seen.

You are therefore forced to boot a different operating system to shrink the disc. I haven't checked, but you may be able to perform the operation using Safe Mode Command Line mode, but you will need to use a command-line tool, such as `DiskPart`. If you still get the corruption errors, you can try booting a Windows installation disc, and access the command-line tools from there (thanks to Ben Voigt for pointing this out).

If you prefer a GUI (as I do), you could use a Windows diagnostic disc, such as [Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), or a commercial partition manger from the likes of [Paragon](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-personal/), but the easiest way is to boot the Ubuntu Live CD and use `gparted`. After configuring the partition sizes you want, you can proceed with the installation from the Live CD without further rebooting (though you may wish to reboot Windows first, to reassure yourself that it is still OK).

Be aware that you are using third-party software, which could be more error-prone than using native Windows, as a diagnostic disc would allow. However, the only diagnostic discs I know of are XP-based and not necessarily up-to-date with any recent disc and file-system changes, while Ubuntu seem to be quite diligent about incorporating them; thus, an external Windows-based diagnostic disc is not necessarily less hazardous. I have used `gparted` for this sort of operation many times, and I have found it very reliable, with lots of checking and warnings if you try to do something potentially disastrous.

All of which adds up to: whatever you do, **take a full back-up before you start**!

Comment: Windows diagnostic disks didn't cease to exist, they ceased to be separate.  Every bootable Windows install disc since Vista (and server versions since Windows 2000) has the ability to, without installing or running any automated repairs, reach a command-line and use a huge variety of system tools.

Comment: @BenVoigt - Thanks, good point. It's also possible that safe mode command line will do it, but I didn't have time to check all the options. I'll update my answer.